# void pointer - Load structure from flash

Tags: c, pointers, avr

I have some example code with a structure stored in the flash memory of an AVR microcontroller.

```
const MyStruct PROGMEM Struct =
{
   .MemberA = 1,
   .MemberB = 2,
}
```

The address of this structure is loaded with this function:

```
const void* StructAddr;
Load(&StructAddr);

void Load(const void** Address)
{
   const void* Temp = NULL;
   Temp = &Struct;
   *Address = Temp;
}
```

What is the reason for a void pointer in this case?
If I try this way

```
const intptr_t StructAddr;
Load(&StructAddr);
void Load(const intptr_t Address)
{
   const void* Temp = NULL;
   Address = &Struct;
}
```

the content of `StructAddr` is 0x00. Why? What is the difference between this two solutions?

Comment: `&Struct` is meant to be `StructAddr` or what? Please post the real code.

Comment: Overall, are you asking why function parameters don't change variables in the caller?

Comment: the call to Load in the second example isn't the same as the first example. in the first you have void ** and in the second it is intptr_t, shouldn't it be intptr_t * ?

Comment: @Lundin sorry I´ve forgot the memory struct. I´ve added it to my description.
And thanks for that question... you solve my problem I think :)
I have to pass the intptr_t as pointer, so the function can write to this memory location. That was the missing part which I did not consider.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if no `*` is involved, it cannot be an output parameter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with flash memory in a AVR controller, but in C we usually use `void*` to indicate a piece of memory which we don't know which type it holds(in contrast with, for example, `intprt_t*` representing the address of a piece of memory where its content should be interpreted as a `int`).

In the first function it is passed a `void**`: you pass the address where a variable of type `void*` is located then by doing `*Address = Temp;` you fill the area in memory pointed by `Address` (thus out of the function the variable is updated).

In the second function you have passed a `intptr_t`: here the same trick doesn't work since youassign to a **local** copy of the memory address `StructAddr` a new value, which is then discarded after the function terminated.

As other in the comments said, you need `intptr_t*` in the signature of the second function and you need to perform the followin `*Address = Temp`.

Comment: So it´s a good solution to use a void pointer for different sorts of structures etc.? Till now I use intptr_t only (if I remind it correct Atmel used a uint8_t* for addresses).

Comment: You should use a `void*` only if you don't know which data is located in the memory address pointed by the pointer. If you know it please use `TYPE*` (where `TYPE` is a C type, since `void*` greatly decrease readability). `intptr_t`serves a totally different purpose (when you want to save in a variable either an `int` or a pointer). Also note that in C just because you say that a memory address is of type `TYPE*` doesn't mean that in the memory there is semantically meaningful data. In other terms you may read a memory chunk as `int*` but maybe inside that chunk there is stored `float`

Comment: Expanding, if for example you know that `StructAddr` is of type `MyStruct`, you should use as function signature `MyStruct**`. No need for `void*` pointers there.

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer please mark it as a correct one... I hate seeing answered question without the green mark :D; or if you are unsatisfied please write an answer of your. I don't mind which you choose.